# how to remove all the occurence of . from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I want to remove all the occurences of `.` from my `array`.

```
var arr = ['...my name is apple', 'my girl .... friend is banana.......'];
```

Here is a code I'm using.

```js
var arr = ['...my name is apple', 'my girl .... friend is banana.......'];

var toRemove = '/\.+/g';  
arr = arr.map(function(el) {
    return el.replace(toRemove, ' ');
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why the above code is not removing every occurrences of `.` I don't know?

Please help me thanks in advance!

Comment: remove quotes from regex statement.

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this.

Comment: @nnnnnn, tag is for inviting answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need quotes for regex. Try this:

```js
var arr = ['...my name is apple', 'my girl .... friend is banana.......'];

var toRemove = /\.+/g;  
arr = arr.map(function(el) {
  return el.replace(toRemove, ' ');
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: i was trying it from yesterday, very minor mistake thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You can always create an extension method as follows.

```
var arr = ['...my name is apple', 'my girl .... friend is banana.......'];
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(s,r){return this.split(s).join("")}
```

And use it as below.

```
alert(arr[1].replaceAll("."))
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sibeeshvenu/b256m3t5/2/) is the working sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and call it in the forEach loop to remove all occurences of '.' character

```
var arr = ['...my name is apple', 'my girl .... friend is banana.......'];

function removeDot(item, index){
   item = item.replace(/[\[\].]+/g, '');
   console.log(item);
   arr[index] = item;
}

arr = arr.forEach(removeDot);
```